# System.Windows.Forms.Button fails to load unless invoked as a subscript

Tags: powershell

Given files TestFile1.ps1 and TestFile2.ps1, in the same directory, with the following content:

TestFile1.ps1:

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

class ButtonContainer {

    [System.Windows.Forms.Button] $button

}

#This prints out the info on Button
[System.Windows.Forms.Button]

echo "Hello World, prove the code got this far."
```

And TestFile2.ps1:

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

.\TestFile1.ps1
```

Why does invoking TestFile1.ps1 directly result in an 'Unable to find type' error but launching TestFile1.ps1 through TestFile2.ps1 does not? And why, after successfully running TestFile2.ps1, does running TestFile1.ps1 no longer produce the same error? I very much appreciate any suggestions you may have!

Note the following terminal output for described behavior:

```
PS [Path Here]> .\TestFile1.ps1
At [Path Here]\TestFile1.ps1:6 char:6
+     [System.Windows.Forms.Button] $button
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unable to find type [System.Windows.Forms.Button].
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound

PS [Path Here]> .\TestFile2.ps1

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    Button                                   System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase
Hello World, prove the code got this far.


PS [Path Here]> .\TestFile1.ps1

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    Button                                   System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase
Hello World, prove the code got this far.
```

Comment: Note that removing LoadWithPartialName and Add-Type from TestFile1.ps1 seems to have no impact on the behavior of the problem, but I included it because it seems to me that having it there should specifically remedy the error I am getting? I'm very open to suggestions.

Comment: The short of it is that a reference to a type via a _type literal_ (e.g., `[System.Windows.Forms.Form]`) inside a `class` definition or in a script file's (`*.ps1`) parameter-definition block (`param(...)`)  fails,
if the referenced type isn't already loaded _before_ execution begins. That is why attempts to load assemblies _from inside the same file_
do not work, which up to at least PowerShell 7.4.1 also applies to the `using assembly` and `using module` statements, unfortunately.